# Should I flag opinionated comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, opinion-based

One time I answered a question and my answer not only worked but was accepted. It got me out of a sticky situation, saved me a lot of work, and continues working beautifully to this day. I am proud to have put that code into production, and was also proud to have the opportunity to share it (in **concept only** of course) on Stack Overflow.

However I received a comment from one user who didn't like the solution (I agree it is kind of hairy). He said something to the effect of:

> This is ugly. If I were you, I wouldn't admit to writing this code.

Now please believe I'm not butthurt about this. I genuinely wanted to know why he thought so, and some comments ensued. It basically boils down to how it was an eyesore to him. Normally I hate eyesores too, but when it comes to writing 100 ugly lines instead of 5000 pretty lines...

**The point of this question is this:** Should I flag comments like this for being opinionated? If we are to avoid opinionated questions and answers, should we do the same in the comments?

**On the one hand:** I appreciate his opinion, I really do. Even if my code works well but someone comes along and shows me a more elegant solution, great! I just learned how to do it better.

**But on the other:** I'm not sure it contributes to the question-and-answer format here. **Plus** we already have upvotes and downvotes. Now whether those should be based on opinion: I will leave that alone.

What do the Meta users say?

Comment: Not for being opinionated, and probably not a flag, but feel free to call it out for having zero substance.

Comment: Flag as too chatty.

Comment: If the comment was only *"This is ugly. If I were you, I wouldn't admit to writing this code"* (with no other context), then I might consider flagging it as "Not Constructive" because it adds nothing of value. If the comment was *ad hominem*, then I would flag it as "Offensive", but it does not appear to be so. But the mods are busy, so I would probably laugh in agreement and let it ride since it was not a personal attack (or it was only a minor jest).

Comment: The title of this question is a real mind-boggler. Why would you flag a comment just because it is *opinionated*? There are few things you could place in a comment that *aren't* opinions. Sure, flag comments that you find offensive or non-constructive (coincidentally, the default flagging choices), but don't just go flagging everything that looks like an opinion.

Comment: I think I know the comment (actually, 2) you were referring to. The problem that I see is, the 1st comment is not constructive, then the 2nd comment is the explanation to the 1st one. It's not really about opinionated or not, but more about usefulness. You could probably flag the 1st one, but if it's okay for you, then just leave it be. On the other hand, if I were you, I would ask them to present what they think a better solution.

Comment: @jww I disagree, I do I see it as a personal attack. As far as I'm concerned, comments that carry that sort of attitude aren't welcome on SO (or anywhere on the entire SE site), and I'd flag such comments everytime. Moderators are busy, but that doesn't mean we shouldn't flag things that are worthy of flagging

Comment: @Bryan - in that case, then you should flag it as "Offensive". But it would be helpful if Gutblender provided a link to the question so we could see some context.

Comment: @jww, I agree, I've gone searching his profile so I could go flag it, but gave up after the first page of answers.

Comment: Just a guess, since it's a bit contradicting the info posted here (1 comment vs 2 comments): [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25371066/define-directive-inside-code-to-separate-code-versions/25371714#comment39565132_25371714)

Comment: @Andrew - yeah, I saw that one too. But I'm not convinced that's the comment Gutblender is talking about. If it is, then it appears he is manipulating this discussion.

Comment: I'm convinced it is the comment he talking about. It's the only comment I could find to one of his accepted answers that comes close to matching the sample comment in his post.

Comment: **Please post a link to the comment in question. I MUST up-vote it!**

Comment: Well, *"my answer not only worked but was accepted"* does not always mean it is *"the best"* nor even close to it. A few times I was building a space shuttle where was a solution for one line. But agreed that giving a comment without *the reason why* is not constructive.

Comment: @CodeAngry http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25371066/define-directive-inside-code-to-separate-code-versions/25371714#comment39565132_25371714

Comment: @avitex That's a huge compliment. I wish I would receive such encouraging feedback on my code. Rumor has it defense jobs pay many peanuts.

Comment: @CodeAngry that may be but I **HATE** working for the government.

Comment: @Gutblender You already are! It's called *taxes*. :)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

> This is ugly. If I were you, I wouldn't admit to writing this code

Opinionated isn't the issue here, comments are often used to express opinion, it's bordering on not constructive, because it doesn't actually help, but what annoys me with this comment is that it's offensive. It's loaded with bad attitude, and I see it as a personal attack. The correct way of wording the comment would have been something along the lines of

> I think you could improve the cleanliness of the code, by [insert description here]

That wouldn't have been offensive and it would have been constructive.

Personally, I'd flag a comment of that nature every time, because as far as I'm concerned attitudes like that and personal attacks aren't welcome on SO (and all of SE for that matter).

Comment: Not constructive, possibly. I wouldn't call it a personal attack though. Rule 2 of [Egoless Programming](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-ten-commandments-of-egoless-programming/): You are not your code.

Comment: @Ajedi32 - IMHO the first part of the comment `This is ugly.` fits what you say. Its not the cleanest way of saying `This is code smell`, but that's basically what it says.  But when someone adds `If I were you, I wouldn't admit to writing this code` that, to me crosses the line. That is baiting, and personal. Asking for trouble. 100% anti-constructive.

Comment: "X is ugly. Do Y instead" would be better than the original but [Beauty Is Our Business](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?BeautyIsOurBusiness). See also, [Taste for Makers](http://www.paulgraham.com/taste.html).

Comment: If we flagged every comment on code that didn't read like it was written by the late Fred Rodgers, we'd essentially be banning Linus Torvalds.

Comment: It wouldn't matter if Linus Torvalds said it or not. At the very least its not constructive and should be flagged as such

Comment: *I think you could improve the cleanliness of the code, by [insert description here]* - Why not being blunt about it: *it's fugly!*. Political correctness messed up the way we talk. These days everybody talks but they say nothing. Just watered down versions of their real opinions. I'd rather get an honest opinion. Whether I care about it... that's another thing. :) [FLAG ME]

Comment: Well, what's so bad about being polite? Further, calling something fugly doesn't provide much helpful information about how to stop making it fugly.  On the other hand, I would say _You could improve the cleanliness of the code by [insert description here]_ ; "I _think_" adds more subjectivity than you necessarily need.

Comment: @CodeAngry, Personally I have no problem with `That code is fugly` (if it was fugly) but `That code is fugly, I wouldn't admit to writing that` isn't okay. It's disrespectful and unwarranted. What's the harm in being polite and constructive though, and instead saying `You could improve this code by [description]`?

Answer (score 13):

First you admit that the comment didn't offend you and actually helped you understand why he thought your code was bad. Leave them be, they're not bothering anyone and they may even help someone else understand that this kind of code is frowned upon by some people.

Answer (score 6):

If it's not actually bothering you and if it's not cluttering up the comments I don't see much point in flagging it. Being opinionated really isn't the problem with the comment, it's problem is that its not really constructive, but you apparently got something out of it anyways. Comments are a reasonable place for opinionated but constructive comments, things like pointing out issues in the code to make it   harder to understand and/or less robust.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that below is the exchange in question; which actually starts with both an opinionated comment and a poor attempt at a joke:

> This solution is utterly hideous. Put it on your resume and you can
>   get a senior engineering position with any defense contractor in the
>   United States.  –  Beta Aug 18 at 21:18

Replying (which is what you did) is actually the most constructive thing done you could have done.

> Imagine going back through an insurmountable amount of code
>   though...this simply puts it in the hands of the preprocessor. What's
>   so hideous about it? –  Gutblender Aug 18 at 21:26

Unless you're dealing with an obvious troll, asking "why" should always be the initial way to go.

> You're using macros all over the place, it's very difficult to figure
>   out what the code is supposed to do, you're inviting macro-related
>   bugs that are notoriously difficult to diagnose, you reimplement
>   everything -- and are already using crude code generation to do it for
>   you, with all the maintenance headaches that come with that, you
>   appear to be using at least three different mechanisms to handle
>   differing code versions where one would do (and coupling them with
>   epoxy) and you're suggesting that perhaps a fourth would help in this
>   particular case. **Don't leave your name on these files.** –  Beta Aug 18
>   at 21:56

Granted, this last sentence "Don't leave your name on these files" doesn't add anything of value to the existing comment, and personally, if I was a moderator, I would not only delete the first comment, but I would delete this very last sentence on this second comment keeping only the rest of the second comment intact because of its actual substance.

That being said, I am not a mod. And moderators are extremely busy and as a matter of priority, I wouldn't flag such a comment since they're dealing with a volume of junk that is so much worse than this (although, if you did flag that first comment "as opiniated" at least, you'd be operating within the rules).

In any case, if such a comment would have been aimed at me personally, this would have been my response to it:

> But I do leave my name on all code files that I write, good or bad.
>   Writing bad code and admitting to it in front of other developers (or
>   in front of the rest of the World) is really the only way that I've
>   grown myself as a developer.